# How to unmarshall single String element (jaxb)?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

This is my xsd scheme:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://gov.com/oos/types/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="sum" type="xs:int"/>
  <xs:element name="docPublishDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  <xs:element name="href" type="xs:anyURI"/>
  <xs:element name="printForm">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:anyURI" name="url"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How I can get an elemnt with name "id"? ()

//I have genereated classes from xsd

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<int> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, ...
```

I don't know what to do next? How to get primitive types value. Everywhere give me an instruction how to get classes complex types? but not single elements like int or string. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your `ObjectFactory` you probably have a mapping for `id` to `JAXBElement<Integer>` or similar.

So you should be able to

```
JAXBElement<Integer> idElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, ...);
```

and then

```
Integer id = idElement.getValue();
```

Comment: Method such this: _JAXBElement<Integer|Long|String> purchaseNumber = unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, Long.class|String.class);_ return me nill value. Source url is set correct

Comment: In ObjectFactory I have only this: _private final static QName _Id_QNAME = new QName("gov.com/oos/types/1";, "id")_

Comment: _@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "gov.com/oos/types/1";, name = "id") public JAXBElement<Integer> createId(Integer value) { return new JAXBElement<Integer>(_Id_QNAME, Integer.class, null, value); }_ I know I can use this to set value to Id, but I dont know how to get value from source http url when i try to parse xml

Comment: Try just `unmarshaller.unmarshal(source)`.

Comment: I was able to do _JAXBElement<Long> purchaseNumber = (JAXBElement<Long>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);_ This give me a _error JAXB error
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://gov.ru/oos/export/1", local:"export"). Expected elements are <{http://gov.ru/oos/types/1}attachments>,<{http://gov.ru/oos/types/1}docPublishDate>,<{http://gov.ru/oos/types/1}href>,<{http://gov.ru/oos/types/1}id>,..._

Comment: I think how I can type to JAXB that I want to parse node single element by name like id, docPu‌​blishDate, etc..?

Comment: You said you want to *get an elemnt with name "id"* in your question but you unmarshal the element `export`.

Comment: This is the problem. I can only type set int, Long to unmarshall xml, but this doesnt work. How to get element with name "id"?

Comment: At this point, I believe, you have to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because it's hard to interpret what you mean by "get element with name id" and "I can only type set int".

Comment: In JackSon XmlMapper I find @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id") point what Object I need. In Jaxb I could not do this. So my solution is choose Jackson at least until I understand Jaxb